# Retrieve all the roles (groups) a user is a member of in ASP.Net Core API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to retrieve all roles the user is in.

This one works ok on my local IIS as I'm the one who is logged in, but when I put API to the server it retrieves not mine roles.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        var userRoles = from id in user.Groups
                         select id.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;

        return Ok(userRoles);
    }
```

If I change WindowsIdentity to IIdentity I'm getting correct User on local and server but I'm not able to access roles.

```
IIdentity user = User.Identity;
return Ok(user);
```

How can I retrieve list of all roles user accessing API is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up that I was very close and it is simple if anyone need it. In the first example replace this one:

```
WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

with that one:

```
var user = User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
```